# Nativescript Unable to instantiate activity

Tags: android, nativescript

I am trying the most basic steps of the hello world here:
https://docs.nativescript.org/tutorial/chapter-1

I have got to the spinning apple working on iOS but when I try and launch on Android I get the following exception.

What can I do to investigate further or resolve?

CLI: 2.5.0
cross platform modules: 2.5.0
plugins: 2.5.0

running on a physical device with Android 5.0.2

```
An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{org.nativescript.HelloWorld/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.tns.NativeScriptActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.nativescript.HelloWorld-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.nativescript.HelloWorld-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2371)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2522)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:167)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1417)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5537)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:956)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:751)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.tns.NativeScriptActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.nativescript.HelloWorld-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.nativescript.HelloWorld-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1070)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2361)
... 10 more
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tns.NativeScriptActivity
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample code, where this behavior could be reproduced? In the meantime, you could delete `platforms` and `node_modules` folders and to build again the project with `tns run android`.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help. Here is the project. There is not much to it: https://github.com/zorro2b/NativeScriptHelloWorld

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is a bug. See issue and associated discussion here:
https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/3637